# Django Form add class to div, input field and label

Tags: django, django-forms

This is the html django form generated for an ImageField

```
<div id="div_id_image" class="form-group"> 
    <label for="id_image" class=""> Image </label> 
    <div class=""> <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" class="clearablefileinput form-control-file" id="id_image"> 
</div>
```

Now, I can write custom html code to customize this field. But, my use-case is just to add 3 classes, one for the outer div, one for the label and one for the input field itself.
Is it possible to add these 3 classes in django form without writing any custom html code

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. use "django-widget-tweaks" tools. It will give you full flexibility in your form.

check out the official documentation:

https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/

If you want to add only class name from form.py
(you can try this but code is not tested)

```
from django import forms

class xyzform(forms.ModelForm):
    x= forms.CharField(widget= forms.TextInput
                           (attrs={'class':'some_class',
                   'id':'some_id'}))
    y= forms.CharField(widget= forms.TextInput
                           (attrs={'class':'some_class',
                   'id':'some_id'}))
    class Meta:
        model = xyzModal
        fields = [
        'x',
        'y'
        ]
```

Comment: Documentation seems like pointing to modifying that on the html part. I am looking for a way to modify that in forms.py file not in form.html file.

Comment: check the update. you can try this but code is not tested.

Comment: But that only adds class on input field...No on label or div tag